# How does one use `AE.framework` (in `CoreServices.framework`) to manually build and send events?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, appleevents

I previously used the `ScriptingBridge.framework`, but found that the performance was terrible for what I was doing (retrieving very large lists of reminders), whereas the AppleScript equivalent is much faster due to the way it constructs the request as a single event, which `ScriptingBridge.framework` sacrificed in exchange for a more object-oriented interface.

Searching the internet turned up no relevant results as the results were polluted with results about Apple's (publicity) events.

How is `AE.framework` actually used?

Comment: Documentation: [Apple Event Manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/apple_event_manager?language=objc) and [Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/apple_events?language=objc). Instead take a look at [Scripting Support](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scripting_support?language=objc).

Comment: Can't ScriptingBridge construct the request as a single event?

Comment: @Willeke It can map the array to a certain member of all the elements, but, as far I can see, it can’t filter the array the way AppleScript can (e.g. get all reminders that are incomplete). You would have to manually check the completed status of each member, or map the array to the completed status and search the array for any false values, then get the elements at those indices. Either way, it would take at least two requests.

Comment: Scripting Bridge says it can [Efficiently Enumerating and Filtering Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/ImproveScriptingBridgePerf/ImproveScriptingBridgePerf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH6-DontLinkElementID_7). But Scripting Bridge has its limits.